# Why * in /etc/security/limits.conf doesn't include root user?

Tags: linux, limit, ulimit

I'm running a java program as **root** on a linux machine. In order to increase the `Max open files` limitation, I added the following lines into `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
*       soft    nofile  1000000
*       hard    nofile  1000000
```

However when I check the running program by `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`, it still tells me that the `Max open files` is **65536**. Until I added another two lines into `/etc/security/limits.conf`, the `Max open files` could be changed to **1000000**

```
root       soft    nofile  1000000
root       hard    nofile  1000000
```

I can see the comments from `limits.conf`, it says that

> the wildcard *, for default entry.

So when I use * as default entry, doesn't it include **root** user? Why?

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Try it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, it doesn't include **root** user. Looks like it has been done by design. From

```
man 5 limits.conf
```

> NOTE: group and wildcard limits are not applied to the root user. To
>   set a limit for the root user, this field must contain the literal
>   username root.

Comment: Can you link to an online copy of the man page that includes that sentence? Because, for example, [this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html) and [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) don’t.

Comment: A bit late, but Scott, in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (server), if you type in the terminal `man 5 limits.conf`, in line 23 it is listed exactly like that

Comment: On redhat/centos * limits are applied to root also, and there is no mention of root in man for limits.conf.