# StreamSets Data Collector Installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, config, streamsets

I am having trouble manually installing the Full Tarball of StreamSets Data Collector. I am running Ubuntu in a VM setting with over 30GB of storage space.

I have read [the Manual Page](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Installation/Installing_the_DC.html#task_bt1_zcp_kq) from the StreamSets website, but it's not useful.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. I have downloaded the full tarball to my `Home/Downloads`
2. I have extracted the tarball to my `Home/Downloads` folder and I have the directory `streamsets-datacollector-3.13.0` with all of its subdirectories
3. Now when I try `bin/streamsets dc` I get the following errors:

```
WARN: could not determine Java environment version; expected 1.8, which are the supported versions
Configuration of maximum open file limit is too low: 1024 (expected at least 32768).
```

I have downloaded all java files using `apt install java*`
and I have tried to change the limits in the `/etc/security/limits.conf`
as proven below:

```
#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

# End of file
*                soft     nproc          33000
*                hard     nproc          33000
*                soft     nofile         33000
*                hard     nofile         33000
```

I even did a system reboot after. However, when I type `ulimit -n` it still gives me the default `1024`.

How should I fix this error?

Comment: Please do `java -version` and edit your question to include the response. As stated in the installation requirements, SDC requires Oracle Java 8 or OpenJDK 8. Also, the `*` in `/etc/security/limits.conf` applies to all users *except* root, so if you are running as root (and you really shouldn't) you will need to add two more lines with `root` in the first column.

Comment: See this question on the limits.conf/root thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991351/why-in-etc-security-limits-conf-doesnt-include-root-user

Answer (score 0):

you just need type "ulimit -n 32768" to change